# Grouping results after join and having clause

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

Let's say I have three tables (mysql):

**recipes**

```
+----+----------------+--------------+
| id |     title      |   image      |
+----+----------------+--------------+
|  2 | recipe title 1 | banana image |
|  3 | recipe title 2 | potato image |
+----+----------------+--------------+
```

**ingredient**

```
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+
| id | recipe_id | food_id | quantity_kg   |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+
|  1 |         2 |      36 | 2.5           |
|  2 |         3 |      37 | 1.5           |
+----+-----------+---------+---------------+
```

**food**

```
+----+---------+-------+-----------+----------+
| id |  name   | price | foodType  | unitType |
+----+---------+-------+-----------+----------+
| 36 | carrot  |     2 | vegetable | kg       |
| 37 | chicken |    12 | meat      | kg       |
+----+---------+-------+-----------+----------+
```

Now, I want to get all the recipes that are vegetarian, i.e. that don't contain any foods where foodType is 'meat' (or other animal product).

How do I perform such query?

Here is what I've tried so far:

```sql
SELECT
  recipe.id as recipeId,
  recipe.title as title,
  food.type as foodType
FROM recipe
INNER JOIN ingredient on ingredient.recipe_id = recipe.id
INNER JOIN food on food.id = ingredient.aliment_id
HAVING 
  food.type <> 'meat' AND
  food.type <> 'seafood' AND
  food.type <> 'fish' 
ORDER BY recipeId
```

This works (I get only vegetarian recipes) BUT it duplicates all the recipes, as long as they have multiple ingredients. eg. :

```
+----------+--------+----------+
| recipeId | title  | foodType |
+----------+--------+----------+
|        5 | titleA | type1    |
|        5 | titleA | type2    |
|        5 | titleA | type3    |
|        8 | titleB | type2    |
|        8 | titleB | type5    |
|        8 | titleB | type1    |
|        8 | titleB | type3    |
+----------+--------+----------+
```

What I want to obtain is:

```
+----------+--------+
| recipeId | title  |
+----------+--------+
|        5 | titleA |
|        8 | titleB |
+----------+--------+
```

I already tried getting rid of 'foodType' in the SELECT clause, but if I do so, mysql tells me : "Unknown column 'food.type' in 'having clause'"

I already tried to GROUP BY 'recipeId' right before HAVING clause, but I get that error : "Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'myDb.food.type' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause" (I understand that error).

I guess it has to do with something like "Grouping results after join and having clause", but I might be wrong...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You don't have a `GROUP BY` clause, so you shouldn't have a `HAVING` clause. Use `WHERE` instead
- Remove the unwanted columns from your `SELECT`
- Because the joins are across 1:many relationships but you're only selecting on the "one" side, you probably also want `SELECT DISTINT` instead of just `SELECT`

Also, you have another issue: The logic of your query isn't actually correct, even though it's returning apparently correct results with such a small set of sample data.

When looking at composition, you probably want to use `EXISTS` and a subquery. Perhaps something like this (untested):

```sql
SELECT
  recipe.id as recipeId,
  recipe.title as title,
  food.type as foodType
FROM recipe r
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT food.type
   FROM ingredient INNER JOIN food on food.id = ingredient.aliment_id
   WHERE ingredient.recipe_id = r.id AND 
      food.type IN ('meat', 'seafood','fish')
  )
ORDER BY recipeId
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I did not know about  EXISTS command + subquery. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

just exclude all recipes which have at least one meat ingridient
(i did it 10 years ago even without sql)

```
SELECT recipe.id, recipe.title FROM recipe
WHERE recipe.id NOT IN (
   SELECT
      recipe.id,
   FROM recipe
   INNER JOIN ingredient 
      on ingredient.recipe_id = recipe.id
   INNER JOIN food 
      on food.id = ingredient.aliment_id
      AND food.type IN ('meat', 'seafood', 'fish') 
)
ORDER BY recipeId
```